# When choosing numbers for countries, put the numbers that follow by jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

now I have a problem and I want to solve it

I created a site that guesses numbers randomly, and when adding a number of countries I need to add the numbers that are after the country number, which are like 10 after +20 in Egypt, I created a code through the rule if it is not practical

the jq Code :

```
 $( ".countrycode select" ).change(function() {
    var ccs = document.querySelector(".companycode select"), countrycs = $(".countrycode select").val();
  if ( countrycs === "966") {
    var optcont = "<option value='50'>50</option>" + "<option value='53'>53</option>" + "<option value='54'>54</option>" + "<option value='55'>55</option>" + "<option value='56'>56</option>"  + "<option value='58'>58</option>" + "<option value='59'>59</option>"  ;
    ccs.innerHTML = optcont;
    } else if ( countrycs === "20") {
      var optcont = "<option value='10'>10</option>" + "<option value='11'>11</option>" + "<option value='12'>12</option>"  ;
      ccs.innerHTML = optcont;
    } else if ( countrycs === "971") {
      var optcont = "<option value='50'>50</option>" + "<option value='52'>52</option>" + "<option value='54'>54</option>" + "<option value='55'>55</option>" + "<option value='56'>56</option>" + "<option value='58'>58</option>" ;
      ccs.innerHTML = optcont;
    } else if ( countrycs === "964") {
      var optcont = "<option value='73'>73</option>" + "<option value='74'>74</option>" + "<option value='75'>75</option>" + "<option value='76'>76</option>" + "<option value='77'>77</option>" + "<option value='78'>78</option>" + "<option value='79'>79</option>" ;
      ccs.innerHTML = optcont;
    } else if ( countrycs === "213") {
      var optcont = "<option value='5'>5</option>" + "<option value='6'>6</option>" + "<option value='7'>7</option>" ;
      ccs.innerHTML = optcont;
    } else if ( countrycs === "962") {
      var optcont = "<option value='79'>79</option>" ;
      ccs.innerHTML = optcont;
    } else if ( countrycs === "965") {
      var optcont = "<option value='5'>5</option>" + "<option value='6'>6</option>" + "<option value='9'>9</option>" ;
      ccs.innerHTML = optcont;
    } else if ( countrycs === "218") {
      var optcont = "<option value='91'>91</option>" + "<option value='92'>92</option>" + "<option value='94'>94</option>" + "<option value='95'>95</option>" ;
      ccs.innerHTML = optcont;
    }
```

pls help

Comment: Are you talking about phone number country codes?

Comment: I am talking about the numbers that follow the country numbers, such as:
+201050939334
The number after +20 is “10” that's what I mean

Comment: You need to know how many digits are the country code, so you know how many to skip to get the rest?

Comment: The person who enters the guesswork selects these corridors, which is a rule if a process is adding too many countries.

Comment: It's really unclear what you're doing. You said the website guesses numbers.

Comment: see that : [img](https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/177382458_762711354315027_8853535817889681043_n.png?_nc_cat=110&ccb=1-3&_nc_sid=58c789&_nc_ohc=w1BpWay4CfUAX_mxh4g&_nc_ad=z-m&_nc_cid=0&_nc_ht=scontent.xx&oh=5c15ef62dea1360c18232ddbe0f966f9&oe=60A77641)

Comment: That image doesn't make it any clearer. What is it estimating?

Comment: I want him to choose the country code and the dialing code that comes after the country code, do you understand me?

Answer (score 0):

Ok Mohamed  <sup>for me</sup> Simple way is by using `data` attribute

- Add `data` attribute to `<option>` like this `<option data-numbers ="[10 , 11 , 12]"` and you can get it by `$('option:selected' , this).data('numbers')`
- Use `.each` in `.change` event to loop through the array of codes the append it in options += `<option>`
- Use `$('.companycode select').html(options);` to change the `companycode select` with the new options

```js
$('.countrycode select').on('change' , function(){
  const codes = $('option:selected' , this).data('numbers'); // Get the array of codes
  let options = '';                                          // define options before update it inside the loop .. you can set it to options = '<option value="">Select Company Code</option>'
  $.each(codes , function(i , code){                         // loop through the array of codes
    options += `<option value=${code}>${code}</option>`;     // update options with the codes in array
  });
  $('.companycode select').html(options);                    // change the comapnycode select
}).change();                                                 // .change() at the end here will fire this change event onload
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="countrycode">
  <select>
    <option value="20" data-numbers ="[10 , 11 , 12]">Egypt +20</option>
    <option value="971" data-numbers ="[50 , 52 , 53 , 54 , 55 , 56 , 58]">United Arab Emarates +971</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="companycode">
  <select></select>
</div>
```

Comment: If you use `.data('numbers')` jQuery will automatically parse it as JSON.

Comment: Praise be to God, thank you, my friend, thanks to you, the problem has been solved

Comment: You're totally welcome ya sahby @MohamedAnwar .. Have a great day :-)  .. charlietfl's answer is good as well so take a look at it :-) .. both ways will work fine :-)

Answer (score 0):

Create an object with all your values and use those to build the new `<option>`

```js
function getOptions(code) {
  const countryData = {
    20: ["10", "11", "12"],
    971: ["50", "52", "54", "55", "56", "58"],
    964: ["73", "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79"],
    966: ["50", "53", "54", "55", "56", "58", "59"],
  }
  const opts = countryData[code].map(v => new Option(v, v))
  opts.unshift(new Option('- Company -', ''));
  return opts
}

$('.countrycode select').change(function() {
  const options = getOptions(this.value);
  $('.companycode select').html(options)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="countrycode">
  <select>
    <option value=""> -- </option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="964">964</option>
    <option value="966">966</option>
    <option value="971">971</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="companycode">
  <select></select>
</div>
```